# Is it possible to change website hosting away from Wix with a domain registered at GoDaddy?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, web-development, wix

I have a website for my Kitchen & bathroom Remodeling business. I want to change the hosting of my website due to poor performance of our current host (Wix). Our domain name is registered with GoDaddy.

Is there any way to change the web hosting? If this is not possible, would I need to rebuild my website?  Can I move to a new platfrom such as WordPress or static HTML with CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: Hosting can be changed. This site works on one question per post. And asking for "best" is asking for opinions, which is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you can easily point your domain name to any hosting company you want.

The bad news is that Wix has no site export functionality. You will need to rebuild your site on some other platform.  The best you can do is copy your content out of Wix one page at a time.

Presumably one of the reasons that you chose Wix to begin with is that they offer a very easy and non-technical way to create a site. I would **not** advise Wix users to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript to migrate their site. Using a content management system (CMS) is a much better option.  [WordPress (from wordpress.org)](https://wordpress.org/) is the CMS that is most often used.

As far as the mechanics go, you will need to:

#### Choose a new host

There are lots of companies that offer WordPress hosting. Use a comparison article to help you choose one such as [this one from wpbeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-hosting/).

I wouldn't try to point your domain name at your new hosting until your site is all set up there. Most hosting companies will give you a subdomain to work with while you build your site.  Something like `https://myconstructionsite.hostingcompany.example/`

People new to WordPress often get the impression that `wordpress.com` is the "official" hosting company.  However, its WordPress installation is much less flexible than other companies. I would recommend using some other WordPress host.

#### Choose a WordPress theme

The theme of a WordPress site controls the overall look and feel of the site.  It also controls how well the site works with mobile users, how well search engines can crawl the site, and has a big impact on site performance.

You'll want to use a theme that works well in all these areas. Again, I'd recommend consulting a guide such as [this one from wpbeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/best-wordpress-themes/).

#### Create the pages at your site

WordPress lets you create pages through the administration panel when logged into your site with your web browser.  See the [step by step instructions for creating pages](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/create-pages/).

One beginner mistake in WordPress is creating "posts" rather than pages.  Posts are meant for news content whereas, pages are meant for content that will be relevant for a long time.

You can copy and paste the text from Wix into pages in your new site.  You can also download images from Wix and upload them into your new site.

#### Move your domain name

Once you new site is set up, you can move your domain name over to it.  This is a two step process.

1. Set up your hosting company to accept your domain.  This is done through your hosting companies admin panel which is often called "cPanel".  This will allow your hosting company to set up the domain name system (DNS) entries for the domain.  It will also configure their web server to listen for the domain and associate it with the site you created.  Your hosting company should give you two to four name server entries that usually look like `ns1.hostingcompany.example`, ..., `ns4.hostingcompany.example`.
2. Change the NS records at your registrar (GoDaddy). Choose the "custom nameservers" option for your domain to enter the NS records from your web host.